# remove object array with index js jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to remove the specific array added in object order by index . i want when user click second button remove second array. i want something like this.

html:

```
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
```

if user click first button must happened this

js:

```
let obj = [
[fisrtButtonArray],
[secondButtonArray]
];
remove.fistbuttonArray
```

if user click second button i want this
js:

```
let obj = [
[fisrtButtonArray],
[secondButtonArray]
];
remove.secondbuttonArray
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.addEventListener()` function to listen to when buttons are clicked. Then, you can use `.splice()` to remove an element from an array.

```js
let obj = [
  ['first'],
  ['second']
];
let el = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
el[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
  obj.splice(0, 1);
  
  console.log(obj);
});

el[1].addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (obj.length == 1) {
    obj.splice(0, 1);
  } else {
    obj.splice(1, 1);
  }
  
  console.log(obj);
});
```

```html
<button class="button">1</button>
<button class="button">2</button>
```

Comment: I mean buttons with same classes